# How to pass json object key as argument to function

Tags: javascript, arguments

I want to create a function that sorts an json object by two keys which I pass to function as arguments as shown below:

```
function sort_json_key1_then_key2(jsonObj, key_1, key_2) {

    jsonObj.sort(function(a, b) {
        if (a.key_1 == b.key_1) {
            return a.key_2 == b.key_2 ? 0 : +a.key_2 > +b.key_2 ? 1 : -1;
        }

        return +a.key_1 > +b.key_1 ? 1 : -1;
    });

}
```

Take the below json object as example:

```
var obj = [
            {"cl":"8","fare":"500.0","name":"41"},
            {"cl":"7","fare":"200.0","name":"37"},
            {"cl":"10","fare":"200.0","name":"33"},
            {"cl":"9","fare":"500.0","name":"29"},
            {"cl":"6","fare":"500.0","name":"29"}
        ];
```

I call the function to sort by 'fare' then 'cl' as follows:

```
var sorted = sort_json_key1_then_key2(obj, 'fare', 'cl');

var json_string = JSON.stringify(sorted);
console.log(json_string);
```

But I get 'undefined' as output in console. I think I am not correctly passing the keys as arguments to function correctly. Any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: Please read [What is the difference between JSON and Object Literal Notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904131/what-is-the-difference-between-json-and-object-literal-notation)

Comment: Try `console.log(jsonObj)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use [bracket notation instead of dot notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968406/javascript-property-access-dot-notation-vs-brackets). Additionaly as you expect the function to return the result, you should actually return the sorted array. As `.sort()` mutates the original array, you might want to clone the array by spreading it into a new one (`[...jsonObj]`), so that the function is pure:

```js
function sort_json_key1_then_key2(jsonObj, key_1, key_2) {
  return [...jsonObj].sort(function(a, b) {
    if (a[key_1] == b[key_1]) {
      return a[key_2] - b[key_2];
    }

    return a[key_1] - b[key_1];
  });
}

var jsonObj = [{
    "cl": "8",
    "fare": "500.0",
    "name": "41"
  },
  {
    "cl": "7",
    "fare": "200.0",
    "name": "37"
  },
  {
    "cl": "10",
    "fare": "200.0",
    "name": "33"
  },
  {
    "cl": "9",
    "fare": "500.0",
    "name": "29"
  },
  {
    "cl": "6",
    "fare": "500.0",
    "name": "29"
  }
];

var sorted = sort_json_key1_then_key2(jsonObj, 'fare', 'cl');

console.log(sorted);
```

Comment: Feel free to rollback if you disagree with my edit :)